# How can I apply the same style for textbox and combobox in WPF?

Tags: wpf, xaml, combobox, textbox, styles

I have made a BaseStyle, which looks like this:

```
<Style x:Key="BaseStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Control}">
    <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation" Value="None" />
    <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="8,5,3,3" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Control}">
                <Grid>
                    <Border x:Name="BorderBase" Background="White" BorderThickness="1,1,1.4,1.4" BorderBrush="Silver" CornerRadius="4" />
                    <Label x:Name="TextPrompt" Content="{TemplateBinding Tag}" Visibility="Collapsed" Focusable="False"  Foreground="Silver"></Label>
                    <ScrollViewer Margin="0" x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Foreground="{DynamicResource OutsideFontColor}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="BorderBase" Value="1,1,2.4,2.4"></Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate x:Name="InspectorErrorTemplate">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="4">
                        <AdornedElementPlaceholder Name="adornerPlaceholder"/>
                    </Border>
                </StackPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>        
</Style>
```

And have used it this way to apply it to a textbox, which works fine:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}" />
```

Now I thought I can simply use the same style at a textbox of a combobox. So I thought I have to add something in this part:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxTextBox" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Border x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Focusable="False" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" />
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

However, I cannot add something like BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}" in the ControlTemplate to make e.g. the textbox to get a different border when it receives the focus (see IsFocused Trigger in the BaseStyle), or a red curved corner in case the validation is triggered... What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Hi you are working with different border color for different text-box that is the only problem here. There are several other options but I feel the following option is good to go.

You can create your own UserControl keeping a TextBox inside it. You can add a new DependencyProperty- BorderColor property in your UserControl. So that according to the BorderColor property value internally you can change the color of the border. So here you don't have to worry about multiple Style or any inheritance.

Isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

The template for a TextBox is fundamentally different than the the template for a ComboBox. So you'll have to have different templates.

You can have one base style to define the shared properties (like `Padding`, `FontFamily`, etc.) without defining the `Template` property. Then make two more styles: one with `TargetType` set to TextBox; and the other with `TargetType` set to `ComboBox`. Each of these styles will be based on your base style and have additional definition for the template (and other properties that are not shared between the two controls).